# 8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter

Tags: wifi, usb, connection

Can connect to many routers with the usb wifi adapter but on some I get an error. When I do the wpa-suplicant manually with the -dd option I get [**skip - no WPA/RSN proto match**] for the AP I'm trying to connect.  I have tried various options for the proto,key_mgmt,pairwise etc options with no luck. By the way, the settings I've used, work with other routers that have similar Security/Encryption setings. I changed the adapter to a  Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter and get the same results. I guess it must be a driver or configuration issue.  Has anyone else had this issue with a particular router?

**lsusb (only concect one at a time)**

```
8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux myraspberry 3.18.11-v7+ #781 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:07:59 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

**cat /etc/os-release**

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
```

***/etc/network/interfaces***

```
auto lo                                                                                                                                  
iface lo inet loopback                                                                                                                   
auto eth0                                                                                                                                
iface eth0 inet static                                                                                                                   
address 192.168.0.34                                                                                                                     
netmask 255.255.255.0                                                                                                                    
    auto wlan0                                                                                                                           
allow-hotplug wlan0                                                                                                                      
iface wlan0 inet manual                                                                                                                  
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev                                                                                  
update_config=1                                                                                                                          

network={                                                                                                                                
ssid="NETGEAR"                                                                                                                           
psk="1482000000"                                                                                                                         
}
```

**Also tried**
    using *wpa_passphrase NETGEAR 1482000000* (insterted results below in wpa_suplicant file with no luck)

```
network={                                                                                                                                
        ssid="NETGEAR"                                                                                                                   
        #psk="1482000000"                                                                                                                
     psk=fb43ef5d68e1923000a9c3adfd8b6cb727526d7b795be395fc87e5158dbb9d6c                                                                
}
```

**To view connection details...**

```
  sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0  -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf  -K   -dd
```

**Note:** I tried the same command with the -D option with 8192cu  nl80211 and wext with no luck

Output of wpa_sup....command (breaks where I think caused the error)

```
wpa_supplicant v1.0                                                                                                                      
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random                                                                                          
Initializing interface 'wlan0' conf     '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf' driver 'default'     ctrl_interface 'N/A' bridge 'N/A' 
Configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf' -> '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'                                
Reading configuration file     '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'                                                                 
ctrl_interface='DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev' update_config=1                                                                
Line: 5 - start of a new network block                                                                                                   
ssid - hexdump_ascii(len=7):                                                                                                             
     4e 45 54 47 45 41 52                              NETGEAR                                                                           
PSK (ASCII passphrase) - hexdump_ascii(len=10):                                                                                          
     31 34 38 32 30 30 30 30 30 30                     1482000000                                                                        
id_str - hexdump_ascii(len=5):                                                                                                           
 57 69 66 69 31                                    Wifi1                                                                                 
priority=3 (0x3)                                                                                                                             
PSK (from passphrase) - hexdump(len=32): fb 43 ef 5d 68 e1 92 30 00 a9 c3 ad fd 8b 6c b7 27 52 6d 7b 79 5b e3 95 fc 87 e5 15 8d bb 9d 6c 
Priority group 3                                                                                                                         
   id=0 ssid='NETGEAR'                                                                                                                   
WEXT: cfg80211-based driver detected                                                                                                     
wext: interface wlan0 phy: phy0                                                                                                          
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0                                                                                   
SIOCGIWRANGE: WE(compiled)=22 WE(source)=21 enc_capa=0xf                                                                                 
  capabilities: key_mgmt 0xf enc 0xf flags 0x0                                                                                           
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=1, operstate=5                                                                                              
wlan0: Own MAC address: 00:0f:60:05:41:81                                                                                                

Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT                                                                                                  
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0 
[...snip...]                                                                   
Driver did not support SIOCSIWENCODEEXT                                                                                                  
wpa_driver_wext_set_countermeasures                                                                                                      
wlan0: RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver                                                                                            
wlan0: Setting scan request: 0 sec 100000 usec                                                                                           
WPS: Set UUID for interface wlan0                                                                                                        
WPS: UUID based on MAC address - hexdump(len=16): 59 42 aa ef 68 5d 57 b6 8e 2b 35 44 a9 a7 d4 48                                        
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED                                                                                              
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized                                                                                              
EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE                                                                                              
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE                                                                                                 
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
```

Here:

```
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized                                                                                          
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized                                                                                          
ctrl_interface_group=106 (from group name 'netdev')                                                                                      
wlan0: Added interface wlan0                                                                                                             
random: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/random                                                                                                 
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])                                                                                         
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added                                                                                        
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event                                                                                          
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b06 len=8                                                                                                         
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])                                                                                         
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added                                                                                        
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event                                                                                          
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b1a len=8                                                                                                         
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])                                                                                         
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added                                                                                        
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event                                                                                          
wlan0: State: DISCONNECTED -> SCANNING                                                                                                   
wlan0: Starting AP scan for wildcard SSID                                                                                                
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 10 seconds                                                                                         
EAPOL: disable timer tick                                                                                                                
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized                                                                                              
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])                                                                                         
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added                                                                                        
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event                                                                                          
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b19 len=8                                                                                                         
wlan0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received                                                                                                   
Received 3092 bytes of scan results (6 BSSes)                                                                                            
wlan0: BSS: Start scan result update 1                                                                                                   
wlan0: BSS: Add new id 0 BSSID 00:24:b2:59:f6:4d SSID 'CAMSOFT'                                                                          
wlan0: BSS: Add new id 1 BSSID 84:db:2f:3c:c7:45 SSID 'UNITE-C745'                                                                       
wlan0: BSS: Add new id 2 BSSID 86:db:2f:3c:c7:45 SSID 'ScrubIsland-Wifi'                                                                 
wlan0: BSS: Add new id 3 BSSID 00:26:44:77:fc:e4 SSID 'CAMCLARO'                                                                         
wlan0: BSS: Add new id 4 BSSID 20:aa:4b:ce:96:42 SSID 'Default'                                                                          
wlan0: BSS: Add new id 5 BSSID 30:46:9a:10:db:59 SSID 'NETGEAR'                                                                          
Add randomness: count=1 entropy=0                                                                                                        
[...snip...]                                                                                                       
wlan0: New scan results available                                                                                                        
wlan0: Selecting BSS from priority group 3                                                                                               
wlan0: 0: 00:24:b2:59:f6:4d ssid='CAMSOFT' wpa_ie_len=26 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x11 level=-33                                               
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 1: 84:db:2f:3c:c7:45 ssid='UNITE-C745' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=-39 wps                                         
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 2: 86:db:2f:3c:c7:45 ssid='ScrubIsland-Wifi' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=-39 wps                                   
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 3: 00:26:44:77:fc:e4 ssid='CAMCLARO' wpa_ie_len=28 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x11 level=-49 wps                                          
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 4: 20:aa:4b:ce:96:42 ssid='Default' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=-83 wps                                            
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 5: 30:46:9a:10:db:59 ssid='NETGEAR' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11 level=-67 wps
```

Here:

```
wlan0:    skip - no WPA/RSN proto match                                                                                              
wlan0: No suitable network found                                                                                                     
wlan0: Setting scan request: 5 sec 0 usec                                                                                                
wlan0: Checking for other virtual interfaces sharing same radio (phy0) in event_scan_results                                             
wlan0: Starting AP scan for wildcard SSID                                                                                                
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds                                                                                         
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])                                                                                         
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added                                                                                        
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event                                                                                          
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b19 len=8                                                                                                         
wlan0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received                                                                                                   
Received 3093 bytes of scan results (6 BSSes)                                                                                            
wlan0: BSS: Start scan result update 2                                                                                                   
Add randomness: count=7 entropy=6                                                                                                        
[...snip...]                                                                                                      
wlan0: New scan results available                                                                                                        
wlan0: Selecting BSS from priority group 3                                                                                               
wlan0: 0: 00:24:b2:59:f6:4d ssid='CAMSOFT' wpa_ie_len=26 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x11 level=-25                                               
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 1: 84:db:2f:3c:c7:45 ssid='UNITE-C745' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=-39 wps                                         
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 2: 86:db:2f:3c:c7:45 ssid='ScrubIsland-Wifi' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=-39 wps                                   
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 3: 00:26:44:77:fc:e4 ssid='CAMCLARO' wpa_ie_len=28 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x11 level=-49 wps                                          
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 4: 20:aa:4b:ce:96:42 ssid='Default' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=-83 wps                                            
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 5: 30:46:9a:10:db:59 ssid='NETGEAR' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11 level=-63 wps                                             
wlan0:    skip - no WPA/RSN proto match                                                                                                  
wlan0: No suitable network found                                                                                                         
wlan0: Setting scan request: 5 sec 0 usec                                                                                                
wlan0: Checking for other virtual interfaces sharing same radio (phy0) in event_scan_results                                             
wlan0: Starting AP scan for wildcard SSID                                                                                                
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds                                                                                         
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])                                                                                         
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added                                                                                        
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event                                                                                          
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b19 len=8                                                                                                         
wlan0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received                                                                                                   
Received 3091 bytes of scan results (6 BSSes)                                                                                            
wlan0: BSS: Start scan result update 3                                                                                                   
Add randomness: count=13 entropy=12                                                                                                      
Add randomness: count=14 entropy=13                                                                                                      
Add randomness: count=15 entropy=14                                                                                                      
Add randomness: count=16 entropy=15                                                                                                      
Add randomness: count=17 entropy=16                                                                                                      
Add randomness: count=18 entropy=17                                                                                                      
wlan0: New scan results available                                                                                                        
wlan0: Selecting BSS from priority group 3                                                                                               
wlan0: 0: 00:24:b2:59:f6:4d ssid='CAMSOFT' wpa_ie_len=26 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x11 level=-33                                               
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 1: 84:db:2f:3c:c7:45 ssid='UNITE-C745' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=-39 wps                                         
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 2: 86:db:2f:3c:c7:45 ssid='ScrubIsland-Wifi' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=-39 wps                                   
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 3: 00:26:44:77:fc:e4 ssid='CAMCLARO' wpa_ie_len=28 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x11 level=-47 wps                                          
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 4: 20:aa:4b:ce:96:42 ssid='Default' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=-87 wps                                            
wlan0:    skip - SSID mismatch                                                                                                           
wlan0: 5: 30:46:9a:10:db:59 ssid='NETGEAR' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11 level=-63 wps                                             
wlan0:    skip - no WPA/RSN proto match                                                                                                  
wlan0: No suitable network found                                                                                                         
wlan0: Setting scan request: 5 sec 0 usec                                                                                                
wlan0: Checking for other virtual interfaces sharing same radio (phy0) in event_scan_results
```

Here I pressed Ctrl-Break (if not it will loop forever)

Comment: What's your router's security settings? `WEP/WPA/WPA2`? `TKIP/AES/Automatic`?

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/network/interfaces`, try changing `wpa-roam` to `wpa-conf`. Just a hunch.

Also, just in case, add your router's BSSID into your supplicant file:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="NETGEAR"
    bssid=30:46:9A:10:DB:59
    psk="1482000000"
}
```

Comment: Tried the bssid with no luck. 
The realtek USB adapter came with a CD that has the driver's source. Think it has to do with teh driver becasue I have three usb wifi adpaters and all show similar results. However the realtek has an antena which gives it an added range. Going to try to compile it and install it....
Will post back results.

Comment: @Carlos What's your router's security settings?